# Integral of softmax (i.e multi-variate sigmoid) over hyper-cube

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, sampling, jacobian, change-of-variable

Let $n$ and $k$ be a positive integers and $\mathbf{b}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{b}_k \in  \mathbb R^n$ (with $\mathbf{b}_l \ne 0$ for at least one $l$), $c_1,\ldots,c_k \in \mathbb R$. What does the following integral

$$I(\mathbf{b}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{b}_k,c_1,\ldots,c_k): =\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{1}{1 + \sum_{l=1}^k\exp(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b}_l + c_l)}d \mathbf{x}$$

evaluate to ?

## Observations

The 1-dimensional binary case (i.e $n=k=1$) is trivial. Indeed, from
$$\int \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x)}dx = \ln (1 + \exp(x)) + \text{constant},
$$

one gets
$$
\begin{split}
I(b, c) &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + \exp(bx + c)}dx
= -\frac{1}{b} \int_{-c}^{-b-c} \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-z)}dz \\
&= \frac{1}{b}\ln\left(\frac{1 + \exp(-c)}{1 + \exp(-b-c)}\right),
\end{split}
$$
where we've used the change of variable: $-z = bx + c$. In particular, one has

$$ I(-1,0) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x)}dx = \ln\left(\frac{1 + e}{2}\right)
\approx 0.62$$

Comment: I think it's worth noting that your 1-dimensional case is the sigmoid function, but your multidimensional integrand appears to not be the softmax function as commonly defined. see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function

Comment: @AnonymousCoward. It's equivalent.  Just divide through by the numerator, and set $b_l := w_l - w_j$. Forget about the intercepts $c_l$ if you want.

Answer (score 1):

---

## Solution to multi-dimensional binary case (i.e $n \ge k = 1$)

**First ingredient.** One has the following Macluarin expansion (e.g see [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html))
$$\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-z)} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+1}(2^{m+1} - 1)B_{m+1}}{m + 1}z^m,$$
where $B_m$ is the $mth Bernoulli number.

**Second ingredient.** Recall the [multinomial binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n z_i\right)^m = \sum_{|k| = m}\frac{m!}{k_1!\ldots k_n!}\prod_{i=1}^n z_i^{k_i}. 
$$

**Third ingredient.** If $k_1,\ldots k_n$ are real numbers all $\ne - 1$, then
$$\int_{[0,1]^n}\prod_{i=1}^n z_i^{k_i}d\mathbf{z} = \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n k_i + 1}.
$$

Putting things together gives

$$
\begin{split}
\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b} - b_0)}d\mathbf{x}&=
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+1}(2^{m+1} - 1)B_{m+1}}{m + 1}\sum_{|k| = m}\frac{m!}{k_0!k_1! \ldots k_n!}b_0^{k_{0}}\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{k_i + 1}b_i^{k_i}\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+1}(2^{m+1} - 1)B_{m+1}}{m + 1}\sum_{|k| = m}\frac{m!}{k_0!(k_1 + 1)!\ldots (k_n + 1)!}\prod_{i=0}^{n} b_i^{k_i}
\end{split}
$$

## Disappointment

However (assuming I haven't made a mistake somewhere down the line), the above formula is rather cumbersome and dirty. Maybe someone here knows how to rewrite this more compactly using logarithms and exponentials ?